# Keep iOS textView on top of keyboard after app resumes from background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an iOS 9+ app with a `textView` that, when clicked in, opens the keyboard and slides up with it. It slides back down when the keyboard is dismissed. So far, so good.

When the app is sent to the background while the keyboard is open with the `textView` on top of it, then when the app resumes the `textView` is sent back to the bottom behind the keyboard (after a split second), but the keyboard remains open. The scenario is explained in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399488/uitextfield-keyboard-not-hiding-when-app-comes-from-background).

Thanks to that question I have a watcher and can run this:

```
@objc func willEnterForeground(_ notification: NSNotification!) {
  view.endEditing(true)
}
```

...and that works to hide the keyboard "almost" seamlessly.

But I really want the `textView` and keyboard to be exactly as they were when the app was sent to the background. What might cause the `textView` to go back to its baseline position? I'm running through the view controller with breakpoints and, so far, have had no luck finding anything.

EDIT:  You don't actually have to send the app all the way to the background. Just starting the touch gesture to send the app to the background (dragging the virtual home bar up) and letting go will remove the textView (also removes an inputAccessoryView if there is one).

EDIT:  Here is the slow motion screen recording demonstrating the issue:

[image: f the issue]

Comment: If you do that and then immediately set your text view to first responder again does it do any good?

Comment: @PhillipMills Nope, becomeFirstResponder doesn't bring the textView back up on top of the keyboard.

Comment: can you share your code or a gif or pics to show how it was before going to and after coming back from background?

Comment: @AbhishekArora  I can later, but picture a keyboard with a textview on top before going to background, then a keyboard with no textview on top after returning from background.

Comment: @lilbiscuit well i checked one of my own apps just now, and it remains the way it went to background with. Thats why asked you to share code or screenshots.

Comment: @AbhishekArora Screen recording added.